# Triggering Text Message on sales_order_shipment_track_save_after via Shipstation

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shipping, notification

I am attempting to set up a custom trigger so that when Shipstation writes back it sends out a text message via Twilio. I have it working when adding a tracking number from the admin side but does not appear to work when adding tracking number through Shipstation (I am assuming it is using Magentos API). Is there a different event I should be listening to for this?

etc/events.xml

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_shipment_track_save_after">
    <observer name="mywebsite_model_observer_textshipment"
        instance="MyWebsite\Customizations\Model\Observer\TextShipment" />
</event>
```

```
namespace MyWebsite\Customizations\Model\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

/**
 * Class Shipment
 */
class TextShipment implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $track = $observer->getTrack();
        $shipment = $track->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $telephone = $this->makePhoneNumberValid($shippingAddress->getTelephone());
        $trackUrl = $this->getTrackingUrl($track);
        $countryId = $shippingAddress->getCountryId();
        $firstName = $shippingAddress->getFirstname();

        $initialGreeting = '';

        if($firstName == '' || $firstName == null){
            $initialGreeting = 'Hello <MyWebsite> Customer of the Year! ';
        }else{
            $initialGreeting = 'Hi '. $firstName .'! ';
        }

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        //$notifier = $objectManager->create('Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier');
        //$notifier->notify($shipment);


        if($countryId == "US" && $telephone != null && $trackUrl != ''){
            // Your Account SID and Auth Token from https://www.twilio.com/console
            $accountSid = "<AccountSID>";
            $authToken = "<Auth>";

            $serviceSid = "<ServiceSID>";

            // Initialize the client
            $client = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);

            //$this->_logger->debug($telephone . ' telenumber'); 


            // Create a notification
            $client->messages->create(
                // the number you'd like to send the message to
                '+1'.$telephone,
                array(
                    // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
                    'from' => '+<Twilio Number>',
                    // the body of the text message you'd like to send
                    'body' => $initialGreeting . ' Your MyWebsite order has shipped!! You can track it through the following link, ' . $trackUrl . '. It has been a pleasure serving you and look forward to your return. With Love, MyWebsite'
                )
            );
        }

    }

    public function getTrackingUrl($track){

        $trackurl = '';
        if($track->getCarrierCode() === 'fedex'){
            $trackurl = 'https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber='.$track->getNumber();
        }elseif ($track->getCarrierCode() === 'usps') {
            $trackurl = 'https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?qtc_tLabels1='.$track->getNumber();
        }elseif ($track->getCarrierCode() === 'ups') {
            $trackurl = 'https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/returnToDetails?tracknum='.$track->getNumber();
        }
        return $trackurl;
    }

    public function makePhoneNumberValid($number){
        if($number == null){
            return $number;
        }


        $patterns = array();
        $replacements = array();

        $patterns[] = '/-/';
        $patterns[] = '/\(/';
        $patterns[] = '/\)/';
        $patterns[] = '/\+01/';
        $patterns[] = '/\+1/';
        $patterns[] = '/^$/';

        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            $replacements[] = ' ';
        }

        $number = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $number);

        if($number == "0000000000"){
            return null;
        }

        return $number;
    }
}
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue using ShipStation -- doesn't seem to trigger the event `sales_order_shipment_track_save_after`, instead try using: `sales_order_shipment_save_after`

And then in your observer, you can get tracking info using the following:

```
$shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
foreach ($shipment->getAllTracks() as $track) {
    var_dump($track->getData()); // get tracking info
}
```